# Netbeans SVN Commit Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: svn, http-status-code-403, java, forbidden

I have an svn set up on Debian 6

I have access on http://*myserver*/svn/youfood/, I can checkout from Netbeans but when i try to commit, still from Netbeans, i have these errors :

**Netbeans Log**

> svn: OPTIONS of '/svn': 403 Forbidden (http://*myserver*)

**Apache Log**

> [error] [client x.x.x.x] The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001]

Here's my differents conf :

**mods-available/dav_svn.conf**

```
56 <Location /svn>
57         DAV svn
58         SVNParentPath /home/svn
59         AuthType Basic
60         AuthName "Subversion Repository"
61         AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.passwd
62         AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/authz
63
64         Require valid-user
65
66         #SSLRequireSSL
67 </Location>
```

**sites-available/youfood**

```
[...]

43     # SVN & TRAC
44     <Location /svn>
45         DAV svn
46         SVNParentPath /home/svn/
48         SVNAutoversioning on
49         AuthType Basic
50         AuthName "Subversion Repository"
51         AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.passwd
52         Require valid-user
54     </Location>
55
56     <Location /trac>
57         SetHandler mod_python
58         PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
59         PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /home/trac/
60         PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
61         AuthType Basic
62         AuthName "Trac"
63         AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.passwd
64     </Location>
```

**/etc/apache2/authz**

```
21 [groups]
24 dev = user1, user2, user3, user4
25 admin = user1
35
36 [/]
37 @admin = rw
38 * = r
39
40 [youfood:/]
41 @dev = rw
42
43 [/home/svn/youfood]
44 @dev = rw
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans is trying to commit to `/svn`, not `/svn/youfood` - something's not right there.

You can prevent the `403` on `/svn` by setting `SVNListParentPath On`.. but since it seems NetBeans wants to commit to there, you'll likely just get a different error.  Can you try removing the working copy from NetBeans and checkout again from the correct URL path?

Comment: I did specify the correct URL path on my checkout (I enter this one : http://_myserver_/svn/youfood). During checkout config, I was able to see subfolders on this repo and choose the last revision that I made manually. Update seems to return no error, only commit is the problem :( And SVNListParentPath on dont changes anything

Comment: Well, it shouldn't have any knowledge whatsoever of `/svn`, and the fact that it's missing the trailing slash is significant too - it's behaving wrong, and the only thing I can think of is that it's got the wrong repository address stored somewhere.  Try some different SVN client software, like Tortoise or just the command line client; that'll tell us whether the problem is NetBeans or the server.

Comment: Oh god, my bad I totally suck :D The problem didn't come from the repository address, it came from my checkout configuration. I let default configuration on "Local folder" instead of specify a destination folder (c:\youfood for example). It work now, sorry for wasting your time, let's pretend this is fatigue's fault :p Thx for your help ;)

Comment: Haha no worries - glad you've got it worked out.